# Running unix shell TalendJob

Tags: shell, unix, bigdata, etl, talend

I have a issue. I build myTalendJob and I am running myShell succesfully by adding a contextVariable. The command I use is:

./mainJob_run.sh --context_param myVar="/myDirectory/file.txt"

Is it possible to simply run **./mainJob_run.sh** and passing dynamically **--context_param myVar="/myDirectory/file.txt"** avoiding to rewrite it anytime?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question but this is my attempt to answer.
Either:

1. When exporting your job, override the context "myVar" by this given value
2. Write caller script to call mainJob_run.sh appending this additional parameter. I prefer this one as it gives more flexibility
3. Implicit contexts load

Answer (score 0):

You can read your context params from a file.

[image: Talend Example]
With this, you don't need to pass the context params through the shell command, but instead it reads the context params from a file when the job is executing.
Ideally, you should put this in your tPreJob.
After reading the values, you can also pass the context params through a tJavaRow for further processing. This way you can format your context params, or generate new context params based on the input values.

TalendByExample has provided a great guide on how to build a reusable context loading job which you can call from any of your jobs.
https://www.talendbyexample.com/talend-reusable-context-load-job.html